# Download speed much slower on Ubuntu 20.04 - Intel Wi-FI 6 AX201

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, intel, iwlwifi

I recently purchased Dell Vostro 7000. I am running `Ubuntu 20.04` with kernel version `5.8.0-50-generic`. I immediately discovered, that the **download** speed on wi-fi tends to be 5-10x slower, than on my Thinkpad connected to the same network, running *the exact same version of Ubuntu and same kernel version*. Ping and upload speed seems to be +- the same. When dualbooting Windows 10 on the same Dell Vostro I get expected download speed, but only after I disable bluetooth in Device Manager.

Things I tried and did not help:

- update kernel
- update firmware
- change value from 3 to 2 in */etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf*
- disable and blacklist Bluetooth service
- turn off fast startup in Windows

Output of running `lhsw -C network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 00
       serial: 50:2f:9b:c0:0e:04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-50-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.u ip=192.168.0.32 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:602311c000-602311ffff
```